# qt statically linked to a library -> symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: qt, xcode4, static, linker

i’m working on a static library that uses qt.
so far, i am able to build qt sources statically and link them to my library. as soon as i try to include the library to a main application (i use xcode 4 for developing, adding libNTFramework.a to my build phase "link binary with libraries" and setting the user headers path to the frameworks headers) i get several

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: “vtable for NI::NT::ScriptApi::Fields”, referenced from: ScriptApi::Fields::Fields() in libNTFramework.a(Fields.o) ScriptApi::Fields::~Fields() in libNTFramework.a(Fields.o) NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
>   (…)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

errors. when using qt built dynamically the errors do not occur.
checking my library by using

> lipo -info libNTFramework.a

output tells me that everything is built fine for the x86_64 arch:

> Non-fat file: libNTFramework.a is architecture: x86_64

any ideas what i am missing? 
thx in advance!

update: 
here's some code... fields is a singleton object that is created and "managed" by the friend class coponentmanager.

```
class Fields : public QObject
 {
  Q_OBJECT
  friend class ComponentManager;

 public:
  QScriptValue scriptValue() const;  

 public slots:
  void bind(const QString name, QScriptValue control);
  void set(const QString name, const QVariant value);
  QVariant get(const QString name) const;

 private:
  Fields();
  virtual ~Fields();

  QScriptValue m_scriptValue;
  ComponentManager* const componentManager() const;

 };
```

and

```
Fields::Fields()
 {
 }

 Fields::~Fields()
 {
 }

 QScriptValue Fields::scriptValue() const
 {
  return m_scriptValue;
 }

void Fields::bind(const QString name, QScriptValue control)
{
    try {
        if (control.isQObject()) 
        {
            QWidget* widget = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(control.toQObject());
            componentManager()->scriptableWizard()->currentPage()->registerField(name, widget);         
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NonCriticalException(control.toString() + " does not represent a QObject");
        }   
    } catch (...) {

    }
}

void Fields::set(const QString name, const QVariant value)
{
    componentManager()->scriptableWizard()->setField(name, value);
}

QVariant Fields::get(const QString name) const
{
    return componentManager()->scriptableWizard()->field(name);
}
(...)
```

and

```
ComponentManager::ComponentManager(QScriptEngine* const engine,
                                    ScriptableWizard* const wizard,
                                       Application* const application) :
  m_application(application),
  m_scriptEngine(engine),
  m_scriptableWizard(wizard)
 {
  s_instance = this;
  m_scriptApiFields = new ScriptApi::Fields();
(...)
 }

 //! Delete the ComponentManager and all singletons created by it.
 ComponentManager::~ComponentManager()
 {
  delete m_scriptApiFields;
  (...)
 }
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with binary architecture of the library. It tells you that `NI::NT::ScriptApi::Fields` class in your library file (`libNTFramework.a`) is missing definition (implementation) of some of its virtual member function. i.e. you defined some virtual member functions in your header but did not implement them.

Comment: thx for your hint. strange that it works, when i use dynamically linked qt. i'll update my initial post with some code. maybe you see the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason for the ctor and dtor to be private? Also, did you implement those slots?

Comment: the reason is to prevent fields to be created in any other class than the friend class componentmanager. and yes, the slots are implemented. see my update in my initial post.

Comment: @hitme did you find what was the problem? i am having the very same issue